# Select random group of items from txt file

Tags: python-2.7

I'm working on a simple Python game where the computer tries to guess a number you think of. Every time it guesses the right answer, it saves the answer to a txt file. When the program is run again, it will guess the old answers first (if they're in the range the user specifies).

```
try:
   f = open("OldGuesses.txt", "a")
   r = open("OldGuesses.txt", "r")
except IOError as e:
   f = open("OldGuesses.txt", "w")
   r = open("OldGuesses.txt", "r")

data = r.read()
number5 = random.choice(data)
print number5
```

When I run that to pull the old answers, it grabs one item. Like say I have the numbers 200, 1242, and 1343, along with spaces to tell them apart, it will either pick a space, or a single digit. Any idea how to grab the full number (like 200) and/ or avoid picking spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `r.read()` call reads the *entire* contents of `r` and returns it as a single string. What you can do is use a *list comprehension* in combination with `r.readlines()`, like this:

```
data = [int(x) for x in r.readlines()]
```

which breaks up the file into lines and converts each line to an integer.

Comment: Thanks btw, this seems like it will work perfect :D

edit: Tested it, needs to be broken down xP